# How to serve a 10mb+ file that is continuously, incrementally updated to the client?

Tags: javascript, html, http, browser

I have a **10mb+ binary file that is necessary for my client to work**. Every time my client accesses the site, that file is a little bigger. So, consider my client accesses the page 20 times in a day. As with every new access the file has changed a little, it can't be cached, so he will download **at least 200mb** - even if, during the day, the file **only changed 0.1mb**.

Is there any way to avoid that gigantic waste of bandwidth?

Comment: Does it have to be web delivered, or can you use something like Dropbox, or rysnc to only send the differences?

Comment: Cache the first request, and send only the diff for later requests. Apply the diff using Javascript. This is assuming the file is simple text file, else you might have to check for similar alternatives for binary files.

Comment: It must be web-delivered, as in, the final client is a normal website and my clients will receive that file every time they access it, via HTTP/ajax. I was to avoid such download waste taking advantage of the fact the file changes very little.

Comment: @Thrustmaster sure, but how? For example, the first time the user accesses it he gets **version 17059**. So I cache that and send the diff for the next versions. Except 2 months later it will be at **version 26024** and the only thing I have cached is that **version 17059**, so he is still downloading a lot of wasted content. Ideally there should be a way to actively cache the result of applying the diff...

Comment: I suppose you could make a page where you click a button, which downloads the 100MB file into the page itself via ajax and stores it in the DOM, and offers to let the user save the file. Then have a refresh button on the page, which tells the server which version of the file is held in the DOM, and the server sends the patching instructions to the page, which patches the file stored in the DOM, and offers to save the new patch file for the user. Sounds like you'd be reinventing part of rysnc in javascript though.

Comment: @MatthewLock and compromising considerably the user experience too :( The user shouldn't even be aware there is a file.

Comment: @Viclib I'm confused then, how do the clients get the file in order to do their work, and what do they do with the file? Or is something that stays in the browser like a big image or video?

Comment: They don't "get" the file, the file contains essential data that maintains the app working. To be more specific, it is sort of a mathematical knowledge-aggregation app, and that file holds the entire knowledge graph. The user shouldn't be aware of its existence, but it is necessary for the whole system to work.

Comment: Just to be clear, it works perfectly as it is, except it wastes a ridiculous amount of bandwidth as I'm sending the same bytes again and again and it is huge so the impacts are considerable.

Comment: Okay so the file is used internally by javascript running in a web page?

Comment: Hmm yes, it is used only internally. The site, which is a webapp, only starts running when the file is fully downloaded.

Comment: Okay, you could divide the file into chunks on the server, have javascript download the chunks and assemble them into the browser as a single file, and then check with the server occasionally to see which file chunks need updating, and patch the file that's in the browser with the updated chunks. Essentially a simple implementation of rysnc in the browser.

Comment: Yes, I could divide it in properly cached chunks of x mbs and then just join them. Interesting idea, I'll explore it.

Comment: Ok I'll added it as an answer with some links.

Answer (score 2):

On the server you could divide the file into chunks, and have ajax download the chunks and assemble them into the browser as a single file, and then check with the server occasionally to see which file chunks need updating, and patch the file that's in the browser with the updated chunks. Essentially a simple implementation of rsync in the browser.

Handling binary data is tricky with javascript so you might find these libraries and code links handy:

https://github.com/jDataView/jDataView/

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/typed_arrays/

https://gist.github.com/fbuchinger/674212

See "Ox.getChunked" method as that might allow you to just request individual ranges of the file directly from the server.